# asp-action renders action="" instead of the correct URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a method in my controller called "NewJobApp" that works fine and returns the view with "NewJobApp" model.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Consultant/NewJobApp/{agencyID:int}/{userID:int}/{companyID:int}/{jobID:int}")]
public async Task<ViewResult> NewJobApp(int agencyID, int userID, int companyID, int jobID)
{
    NewJobApp nja = await Repository.GetNewJobApp(agencyID, userID, companyID, jobID);
    return View(nja);
}
```

In the view I have a form that should call "SubmitNewJobApp", but when I view the page source, it shows action=""

```
<form id="JobAppForm" class="form-group" asp-controller="Consultant" asp-action="SubmitNewJobApp" method="post" style="text-align: left">

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input id="AgencyID" asp-for="@Model.AgencyID" value="@Model.AgencyID" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="@Model.AgencyName" value="@Model.AgencyName" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="@Model.UserID" value="@Model.UserID" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="@Model.CompanyID" value="@Model.CompanyID" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="@Model.JobID" value="@Model.JobID" type="hidden" />
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Errs))
{            
    @Html.Raw(Model.Errs);
}
<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 8px">&nbsp;</p>

<div class="form-group">
    <label style="width: 120px; text-align: left; display: inline-block;" asp-for="@Model.JobTitle">Job:</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.JobTitle" value="@Model.JobTitle" readonly />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="width: 120px; text-align: left; display: inline-block;" asp-for="@Model.CompanyName">Company:</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.CompanyName" value="@Model.CompanyName" readonly />
</div>

<p style="margin-bottom: 4px;">Enter person search expression:</p>
<input asp-for="@Model.SearchExpression" value="@Model.SearchExpression" style="width: 132px; margin-bottom: 8px;" />
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Get Candidates</button>

<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 8px">&nbsp;</p>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="width: 120px; display: inline-block;" asp-for="ContactID">Contact:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactID, Model.Contacts, "Choose a Contact", new { @class = "myDDL", @id = "contactsDDL" })
</div>

<div class="text-center" style="text-align: right">
    <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the "SubmitNewJobApp" method in the controller, but it never gets called.

```
[HttpPost()]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitNewJobApp(NewJobApp nj)
{
    int id = 0;
    bool is_err = false;
    string err = string.Empty;

    // check data
    if (nj.ContactID == 0)
    {
        is_err = true;
    }

    // check model state
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || is_err)
    {
        nj = await Repository.GetNewJobApp(nj);
        return View("NewJobApp", nj);
    }

    nj.NewRecordID = id;
    return View("NewJobApp", nj);
}
```

Comment: As a side comment: MVC6 doesn't exist. You are using ASP.NET Core

Comment: Is your controller class actually called `ConsultantController`?

Comment: sorry my mistake. my target framework is .Net Core 2.0

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes the controller name is correct.

Comment: Why do you have 2 submit buttons?

Comment: @StephenMuecke its a long answer. the form requires input of a search expression in order to get a list of contacts to populate the drop down - much like populating a second drop-down based on a previous selection. I would like to do this using JavaScript but I can't call the method in the controller from the form because its Async with await that calls a web service. so I just submit the form to get the search expression and return again with the IEnumerable list.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why this doesn't work, but I have a temporary solution.

If I remove the HttpGet template on the method that returns the "NewJobApp" view, the form action now contains a value, and works!

Previous method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Consultant/NewJobApp/{agencyID:int}/{userID:int}/{companyID:int}/{jobID:int}")]
public async Task<ViewResult> NewJobApp(int agencyID, int userID, int companyID, int jobID)
{
    NewJobApp nja = await Repository.GetNewJobApp(agencyID, userID, companyID, jobID);
    return View(nja);
}
```

Now changed to:

```
    [HttpGet()]
    [AllowAnonymous]        
    public async Task<ViewResult> NewJobApp(int agencyID, int userID, int companyID, int jobID)
    {
        NewJobApp nja = await Repository.GetNewJobApp(agencyID, userID, companyID, jobID);
        return View(nja);
    }
```

This is the changed code that calls the "NewJobApp" controller method:

```
        function startNewApplicant() {
        var para1 = @ViewBag.AgencyID;
        var para2 = @Model.Job.UserID;
        var para3 = @Model.Job.CompanyID;
        var para4 = @Model.Job.JobID;
        // var url = "NewJobApp/" + para1 + "/" + para2 + "/" + para3 + "/" + para4; (previous)
        var url = "NewJobApp?agencyID=" + para1 + "&userID=" + para2 + "&companyID=" + para3 + "&jobID=" + para4;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
```

But actually I prefer to use the template because I want the cleaner looking URL.

**My Startup routes:**

```
                app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "signin",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{agencyID}/{contactID}");

            });
```

Comment: did you have custom routes setup in startup.cs?

Comment: @mvermef I've included my Startup routes in the above post. I don't think I needed to add the custom route "signin". I think I just need to add another "/{id?}" to the default route. but now that I've removed all the route templates in the controller methods, they all seem to work, even with 4 or 5 parameters